# Encoded url causes 500 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, urlencode

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var selectedAmenities = "";

        function amenitiesLog(message) {
            $("<div/>").text(message).appendTo("#amenitiesLog");
            $("<br/>").text("").appendTo("#amenitiesLog");
            $("#amenitiesLog").scrollTop(0);

            selectedAmenities = document.getElementById("amenitiesLog").innerHTML;
        }

        $("#Amenities").autocomplete({
            //source: "/Results/GetAmenities",
            source: function (request, callback) {
                var url = "/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities + '&term=' + request.term;
                $.getJSON(url, callback);
            },
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item != null)
                    amenitiesLog(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>​​​​​
```

Which causes this url to be generated and called

```
http://localhost:63320/Results/GetAmenities?selected=%3Cdiv%3EAir%20conditioning%3C/div%3E%3Cbr%3E&term=abc
```

The error I get in Firebug is this

```
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (selected=&quot;&lt;div&gt;Air conditionin...&quot;).
```

What is the solution?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Do you really need to pass HTML code on your GET parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar to this once and I had to declare what my invalid URL characters were. I did this in my web config as:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="600" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,\" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

Where 'requestPathInvalidCharacters' contained the invalid characters, so in my case, I removed the colon as I needed this in my URL.

This worked for me but as to whether there are some security risks here that you need to think about, I don't know.